# Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in base/default/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml on line 30

Tags: magento-1.9, email, shipping-methods

I am trying to add **`SUBTOTAL`, `SHIPPING`, `GRAND TOTAL`** in shipping order email.

I have added the following code in

> base/default/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml

```
<?php
    $_totalData = $_order->getData(); 
    $_sub = $_totalData['subtotal'];
    $_grand = $_totalData['grand_total'];
    $shipping_amount = $_order->getShippingAmount();
?>
```

In the same file `echo` the data's, code following

```
<tbody style="font-size:12px;">
   <tr style="font-size:12px;">
      <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <b>SUBTOTAL </b>                   
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <span>&#8377; <?php echo number_format($_sub); ?></span>                    
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="font-size:12px;">
      <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         SHIPPING           
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <span>&#8377; <?php echo number_format($shipping_amount); ?></span>                    
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="font-size:12px;">
      <td colspan="3"  align="right" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <b>GST</b>
      </td>
      <td  align="center" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <b><span>&#8377; 
         <?php 
            $sub = number_format($_sub);
            $gst_tax = 0.03;
            $gst = $sub*$gst_tax;
            echo round($gst);
            ?>
         </span></b>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="font-size:12px;">
      <td colspan="3"  align="right" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <b>GRAND TOTAL</b>
      </td>
      <td  align="center" style="padding:3px 9px; font-size:12px;">
         <b><span>&#8377; <?php echo number_format($_grand); ?></span></b>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to Preview the mail in `admin->Transactional Emails->shipping email` it is showing an error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/mw/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml on line 30